# How can i get Opportunity stage conversion rate in report

Tags: reporting

I want to calculate opportunity stage conversion rate. I created a report on opportunity history and group by from stage and two stage add custom formula:

Opportunity.Count__c:SUM / PARENTGROUPVAL(Opportunity.Count__c:SUM, ROW_GRAND_SUMMARY, STAGE_NAME)

count is the opportunity custom field which shows 1 for 1 opportunity.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain you're going to obtain the results you want using a Summary Report. You may need to do it using a Matrix Report.

If you look at your current report, in the Grand Total field at the bottom, the numbers you're looking for would be the closed-won or In Production (I assume they're essentially the same?) divided by the numbers at the bottom of each of the other columns such as prospecting, value proposition, etc.

With the data shown, only 12.5% (1/8) of your opportunities are converted from prospecting stage, but 25% (1/4) are converted from value prospecting. In essence, you need to take those numbers and put them into another matrix so you can view them differently. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Your logic make sense but the problem here, How can I implement it in report. Do I need to created joined report to show different matrix?

Comment: You should be able to do this with a Matrix Report. See [Creating A Matrix Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_reports_matrix.htm) in the Force.com Platform Fundamentals. You'll be able to apply formula fields as needed in both columns and rows; something you can't do in a summary report. You can also add columns of cross-filtered data which is one way to show what you want to display.